# Rails, models polymorphic and double foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm developing a "Facebook" like software, where a user can write posts, make comment, and put likes (votes).
A vote can be put on posts both comments. A user can vote his own posts and also other user's post.

So, here my models:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :posts
has_many :votes
```

**post.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
has_many :votes, as: :votable
```

**comments.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
has_many :votes, as: :votable
```

**votes.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
```

(It's polymorphic because it work for comments and posts. I'm doing well?)

My db structure is something like this:
Table Posts (id, user_id, ...)
Table Votes (id, votable_id, votable_type, user_id, ...)

Here the question: How to load the right information where i'm the user_id 16 and i'm looking for the user_id 21 posts?

This is what I want in an eager load statement:

```
select * 
from posts left outer join
    votes on 
        votes.votable_id = posts.id and 
        votes.votable_type = 'Posts' and
        votes.user_id = 16 ---> (My user_id)
where posts.user_id = 21 ---> (user_id i'm looking at)
```

I'm trying to find a way to put the "votes.user_id" condition in a eager_load statement but I can't find a way...

Thanx!

Comment: I tend not to use polymorphic on join models, it doesn't gain much and I almost always want to store something on the table that isn't generic.  Makes it simpler to counter cache, eager load, use :through, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I kept the polymorphic but I change the load procedure, using the find_by_sql, easier to understand for me.